# Compiling source code in debug mode using a CodeDomProvider

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, compiler-construction, codedom

I have some source code I'd like to compile using the `Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider` class, and I want to include stuff that's specific to debug builds (e.g., methods marked with the `[Condtional("DEBUG")]` attribute).

I tried setting the `CompilerParameters.CompilerOptions` property to "/debug", but when I ran the compiled code the debug stuff didn't seem to be included; so I suspect that wasn't the correct way to accomplish what I want.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to set `CompilerOptions` to `/d:DEBUG` which will define the DEBUG preprocessor symbol. That's what conditional compilation is based on, rather than the `/debug` flag - the latter controls whether debug information is emitted.